# JOptionPane : change the Icon

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have this layout in the `JOptionPane`:

```
JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("Do not show this message again.");
String message = "Level loaded successfully";  
Object[] params = {message, checkbox};  
int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(p, params, "Draft saving",
     JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

everything is fine except for the display of the `Icon`..,

Ideally I would like not to have an Icon (hence the `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE`), but I get a `default Icon`.

How can I change this ?

Jason

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [version of the method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon%29) that takes an icon parameter, and pass in null for the icon.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand this answer. The method indicated by the questioner actually delegates to the method you gave, using `null` as an argument for the icon, so I don't see the difference. Furthermore, the `BasicOptionPaneUI.getIcon()` method appears to retrieve a default icon any time it finds that `null` was specified for the icon. So how can calling any of the JOptionPane methods with a `null` icon prevent an icon from being displayed? Have you verified your answer works?

Comment: Garret, you are correct. I did test the solution myself, but to verify, I just copied and pasted the original poster's question and found the real problem - there is an int parameter missing. Instead of calling showConfirmDialog(p, params, "Draft saving", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE), it should be showConfirmDialog(p, params, "Draft saving", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE). This removes the icon.

Answer (score 6):

for example, works as I expected

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class OptionPaneOptions {

    private JPanel options;
    private Object[] items;

    public OptionPaneOptions() {
        options = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        options.add(createOptionPane("Plain Message", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE));
        options.add(createOptionPane("Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE));
        options.add(createOptionPane("Information Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE));
        options.add(createOptionPane("Warning Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE));
        options.add(createOptionPane("Want to do something?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
        items = new Object[]{"First", "Second", "Third"};
        JComboBox choiceCombo = new JComboBox(items);
        options.add(titled(new JOptionPane(choiceCombo,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION), "Question Message"));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JOptionPane'Options");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(options, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static JOptionPane createOptionPane(String message, int type) {
        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(message, type);
        String title = message;
        if (type == JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) {
            title = "Question Message";
            pane.setOptionType(JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
        }
        return titled(pane, title);
    }

     static <T extends JComponent> T titled(T c, String title) {
        c.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OptionPaneOptions test = new OptionPaneOptions();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this is the format @Jesse Barnum was talking about

```
public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,
                                     Object message,
                                     String title,
                                     int messageType,
                                     Icon icon);
```

you supply `int messageType` with the messageType constants that also determines the icon

example: this one outputs a Question icon, using  `JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE`

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Are you OK?","HI",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null);
```

this one outputs a Information icon

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You are reading something","FYI",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The method you're using doesn't specify an icon.

You should use [`showConfirmDialog(Component, Object, String, int , int , Icon)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon%29), which enables you to pass an `Icon` as well.

Comment: Your answer shouldn't rely on external url

Comment: @xenteros well it's the official java documentation. Even though, I edited it in.

Answer (score 1):

To Have no Icon, try this.

```
String[] options = {"Ok", "Cancel"};

int choices = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
  Ann.this, "Do you Want To Exit Calculator ", "Exit Calculator",
  JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, 
  options, options[0]
);
```

Although I am using an `OptionDialog`, you can change it to a `ConfirmDialog`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would work:

```
Image icon = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
  null, "Do you really want to Exit Alarm Clock - By jLab", "Alarm Clock - By jLab",
  JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,icon
);

if (option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
  System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify why should this code make the icon disappear? Should `icon.png` be a nonexisting file?

Comment: I still don't think you understood the question: "I would like not to have an Icon"... The OP just wants to get rid of any icon, not to specify it...

Comment: @peci1: I'm really sorry for the mistake. See I have corrected it. Tell me if you have any issues

Comment: I've edited a few issued with your code, which wouldn't compile before. Now, could you try to explain why is your answer better than the accepted answer (or when it makes sense to use it).